# регулярные выражения для произвольных объектов

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Предположим у меня есть список неких разнотипных объектов, и я хочу искать по этому списку регулярными выражениями.

Вот что я примерно хочу получить:
Определения классов:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, type(self)):
            return self.number == other.number
        return False
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}({})'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.number)

#Тут для простоты классы (Tf, Ts, O) являются наследниками C,
#но в реальной жизни это может быть и не так

class Tf(C):
    pass
class Ts(C):
    pass
class O(C):
    pass
```

1. `re.match((type(C), type(C)))` на `[C(1), C(2), Tf(1), Ts(5)]` возвращает `[C(1), C(2)]` (как и в шаблоне найдено 2 объекта типа `C`.)

2. `re.match((type(C), type(C)))` на `[Tf(1), Ts(5)]`  возвращает `[]`(пустота, так как нет объектов типа С)
3. `re.match((C(1), type(Tf)))` на `[O(1), C(1), Tf(2)]`  возвращает `[C(1), Tf(2)]`(один объект типа `C` по прямому совпадению и один объект типа `Tf` по совпадению типа)
4. `re.match((*type(C)))` на `[C(1), C(2)]`  возвращает `[C(1), C(2)]`(то есть как и в регулярках мне выдало все объекты типа `C`)

Есть ли где-то движок позволяющий такое? (Желательно на питоне, но другой язык тоже подойдет). Я не смог найти..

P.S: Похоже я не очень ясно выразился. Вот смотрите есть у нас регулярка типа такой  `\d{2}` она выдает нам 2 числа из строки. Я хочу точно такое же но чтобы вынимала не числа а типы или объекты которые я указал в шаблоне, и вынимала не из строки а из списка. То есть регулярки ищут по символам, а мне надо искать по всем типам вообще.

Comment: Вы можете привести несколько примеров того что показывает `type(C)` для разных объектов?

Comment: @MaxU добавил примеры

Comment: `re.find` это некая функция которая ищет по регулярному выражению. (сменил на `re.match` чтобы не смущало). Надо просто код классов чтобы было на чем тестить?

Comment: добавил определения классов

Comment: А что должно возвращать: `re.match((type(C), type(C))) на [Tf(1), Ts(5)]`? В смысле, как вы хотите, чтобы это отрабатывало? Вы просто хотите проверить принадлежность родительскому классу?

Comment: `(*type(C))` это SyntaxError. Возвращать `[]` когда нет совпадения неверно (следует либо исключение выбрасывать, либо None), так как пустой список может быть верным значением для какого-нибудь ввода. Язык, который из примеров в вопросе следует, очевидно, что нигде не существует (если кто-то точно такую же задачу не имел) -- его легко реализовать. Если вас только конкретный пример интересует, то отразите это в заголовке. В противном случае не ясно, что вы в ответе хотите увидеть -- пересказ теории формальных языков?

Comment: @AndrioSkur, вы случайно не это ищете: `type(Tf(1)).mro()`?

Comment: @jfs чуть более развернуто объяснил. "(*type(C)) это SyntaxError." мне не суть важно как конкретно обьявлять шаблон. В этом случае мне нужно как-то найти любую последовательность объектов типа `C` в списке. Но я не хочу это делать отдельной функцией, я хочу использовать что-то типа регулярок

Comment: @MaxU нет не это

Comment: @MaxU `re.match((type(C), type(C))) на [Tf(1), Ts(5)]` ну это работает примерно так же как  `re.match(r'\d{2}', 'sas12')`

Comment: @AndrioSkur, я могу себе представить поиск по строковой репрезентации объекта при помощи регулярок. Для того, чтобы делать то что описываете вы надо, по-моему, какой-то свой монстр писать...

Comment: @MaxU О, вот я и спрашиваю может где-то уже есть такой монстр, который неплохо работает. Зачем мне тогда писать свой?)

Comment: @AndrioSkur, я пока так и не понял/увидел пользы от такого монстра.Если бы это было действительно необходимо, то наверное это уже было бы реализовано...

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял, то как то так ?

```
l = ['12int3sfd', 'wefwestr111', '!typedsfdf', '!floatdfdf']
r = re.compile("type|float")
for i in filter(r.search, l):
    ...:     print(i)
    ...:     
!typedsfdf
!floatdfdf
```